# -Wimplicit-function-declaration while make module qmi_wwan

Tags: linux, gcc, makefile, module

my Makefile:

```
obj-m += qmi_wwan.o

CFLAGS += -Werror -Wno-implicit-function-declaration

all:
    make -C /lib/modules/5.10.103-v7l+/build M=$(PWD) modules
clean:
    make -C /lib/modules/5.10.103-v7l+/build M=$(PWD) clean
```

Error i get while compiling:

```
warning: implicit declaration of function ‘dev_sw_netstats_tx_add’; did you mean ‘dev_sw_netstats_rx_add’? [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
warning: implicit declaration of function ‘dev_addr_mod’; did you mean ‘dev_addr_add’? [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
```

Additional informations:
I'm configuring qmi_wwan module to add Quectel RM520N as it was explained -> in this [thread](https://lore.kernel.org/linux-usb/tencent_E50CA8A206904897C2D20DDAE90731183C05@qq.com/)

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. I was compiling `qmi_wwan` from kernel **5.15.y** on my current kernel **5.10.y**, that's why I've got this error.
After compiling `qmi_wwan` driver from **5.10.y**, the problem disappeared.